# JavaScript getting the URL in browser from an iframe

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-browser

I am using a free site. that free site has a free app. In that free app I can run PHP code from my server.

What JavaScript code can get me the URL of the address showing in browser called from an iframe on my server?

Thanks
-Ed

Comment: Javascript isn't running on your server.

Comment: actually it is running on the server cause I used other scripts. I just can't get the parent url or the root url. Hummm

Comment: Unless you're using Node.js (you aren't), it is not running on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var addressBarURL = top.location.href;`

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you right, you want to get the URL of the main window from the iframe. If so (from the page in the iframe):

```
window.parent.location.href
```

NB: Security policies on browsers will not allow you to access the this property if the main window and the iframe are accessed on different domains.

Comment: Yes the Iframes are from a different domain. This is a facebook app. Is there not a way to get the browser url. I need to get some vars from there. There must be a way. thanks for your fast reply btw.

Comment: "There must be a way." Unless you can plant JS on the Facebook page (I don't know) then I wouldn't be so certain. If you can implant code on the Facebook page then you can use the query string to pass once-off data to the iframe. If you want to pass data dynamically (both ways), you can alter the #hash of win2 (the src of the iframe in win1 and the window.hash property in win2). That can be polled from both windows and used to hackishly allow cross-domain JS calls. But, if you can't plant JavaScript in win1, then I think you're stumped.